# c++ error : (private data member) was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, friend-function

Say I have a class like so:

```
class Ingredient
{
    public:
        friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Ingredient& target);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Ingredient& data);
    private:
        Measure myMeas;
        MyString myIng;
};
```

In this overloaded friend function, I'm trying to set the value of `myIng`

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Ingredient& target)
{
    myIng = MyString("hello");
}
```

In my mind, this should work because I'm setting the value of a private data member of the class Ingredient in a friend function and the friend function should have access to all the private data members right?

But I get this error:  `‘myIng’ was not declared in this scope`
Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you need to be be explicit that you are accessing a member of the `target` parameter, not a local or global variable:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Ingredient& target)
{
    target.myIng = MyString("hello"); // accessing a member of target!
    return in; // to allow chaining
}
```

The above will work exactly because the operator is a `friend` of `Ingredient` as you mention. Try removing the friendship and you will see that accessing `private` members will no longer be possible.

Also, as Joe comments: stream operators should return their stream parameter so that you can chain them.

Comment: And don't forget to return `in`.

Answer (score 2):

In that scope, there is nothing called `myIng`. The error is pretty clear on that. Its `Ingredient& target` who has a `myIng` member, so you should write:

```
target.myIng = MyString("hello");
```